# How to create jQuery function that works without selector?

Tags: jquery, function

I want to create a extension for jQuery like `$.ajax()` or `$.extend()` but unlike `$("selector").css()`.

So i can call my custom jQuery function like this: `$.myCustomFunction("args");`

Comment: This article can help http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/

Comment: why do you want to do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just assign it to the `jQuery` object.

```
jQuery.myCustomFunction = function() {};
```

Comment: Thanks, it's worked for now. As i remember i tried this solution but i may did something wrong. Thanks again.